# How to integrate ts-transformer-keys with quasar framework (vue3/typescript/vite/rollup)

Tags: typescript, vite, quasar-framework, rollupjs

I'm trying to use **ts-transformer-keys** with **quasar** but following code results in an error.

I've configured like described in the [Rollup (with rollup-plugin-typescript2)](https://github.com/kimamula/ts-transformer-keys#rollup-with-rollup-plugin-typescript2) example with default versions of packages, then I've updated the related packages to the latest versions, but got the same error in both cases.

How to configure app to fix an error?

**MyClass.ts** :

```
import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';
// keys();
interface Foo {
  foo: string;
}
const fooKeys = keys<Foo>();
console.log(fooKeys[0]);
```

**Error** :

```
PS C:\.Sln\My.Proj> npm run build

> my.proj@0.0.1 build
> quasar build
 Build mode............. spa
 Pkg quasar............. v2.13.0
 Pkg @quasar/app-vite... v1.6.2
 Pkg vite............... v2.9.16
 Debugging.............. no
 Publishing............. no

 App •  WAIT  • Compiling of SPA UI with Vite in progress...
"keys" is not exported by "node_modules/ts-transformer-keys/index.js", imported by "src/tmp/@my-temp/MyClass.ts".
file: C:/.Sln/My.Proj/src/tmp/@my-temp/MyClass.ts:6:9
5:
6: import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';
            ^
7: keys();
8: interface Foo {
C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\parseAst.js:279
        base = Object.assign(new Error(base.message), base);
                             ^

Error [RollupError]: "keys" is not exported by "node_modules/ts-transformer-keys/index.js", imported by "src/tmp/@my-temp/MyClass.ts".
    at Object.error (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\parseAst.js:279:30)
    at Module.error (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:14040:28)
    at Module.traceVariable (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:14478:29)
    at ModuleScope.findVariable (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:12901:39)
    at Identifier.bind (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:8516:40)
    at CallExpression.bind (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:6061:23)
    at CallExpression.bind (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:10123:15)
    at ExpressionStatement.bind (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:6061:23)
    at Program.bind (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:6057:28)
    at Module.bindReferences (C:\.Sln\My.Proj\node_modules\rollup\dist\shared\rollup.js:14036:18) {
  binding: 'keys',
  code: 'MISSING_EXPORT',
  exporter: 'C:/.Sln/My.Proj/node_modules/ts-transformer-keys/index.js',
  id: 'C:/.Sln/My.Proj/src/tmp/@my-temp/MyClass.ts',
  url: 'https://rollupjs.org/troubleshooting/#error-name-is-not-exported-by-module',
  pos: 36,
  loc: {
    column: 9,
    file: 'C:/.Sln/My.Proj/src/tmp/@my-temp/MyClass.ts',
    line: 6
  },
  frame: '5: \n' +
    "6: import { keys } from 'ts-transformer-keys';\n" +
    '            ^\n' +
    '7: keys();\n' +
    '8: interface Foo {',
  watchFiles: [
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\vite\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\vue\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\@quasar\\extras\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\quasar\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\@vue\\runtime-dom\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\@vue\\runtime-core\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\@vue\\shared\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\vue-router\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\pinia\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\vue-i18n\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\@vue\\reactivity\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\pinia\\node_modules\\vue-demi\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\@vue\\devtools-api\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\@intlify\\shared\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\@intlify\\core-base\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\axios\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\ts-transformer-keys\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\@intlify\\message-compiler\\package.json',
    'C:\\.Sln\\My.Proj\\node_modules\\flag-icons\\package.json'
  ]
}

Node.js v18.17.1
```

**quasar.config.js** :

```
/* eslint-env node */
const { configure } = require('quasar/wrappers');
const packageJson = require('./package.json');
const path = require('path');
const keysTransformer = require('ts-transformer-keys/transformer').default;
const resolve = require('@rollup/plugin-node-resolve');//.default;
const typescript = require('@rollup/plugin-typescript');//.default;

module.exports = configure(function () {
    return {
        build: {
            env: {
                appVersion: packageJson.version,
            },
            alias: {
                boot: path.join(__dirname, './src/boot'),
                components: path.join(__dirname, './src/components'),
                layouts: path.join(__dirname, './src/layouts'),
                router: path.join(__dirname, './src/router'),
                stores: path.join(__dirname, './src/stores'),
                '@my-temp': path.join(__dirname, './src/tmp/@my-temp'),
            },
            vitePlugins: [
                [
                    require('@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n').default,
                    {
                        include: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/localization/**'),
                    },
                ],
                [
                    resolve(),
                    typescript({
                        transformers: [
                            (service) => ({
                                before: [keysTransformer(service.getProgram())],
                                after: [],
                            }),
                        ],
                    }),
                ],
            ],
            target: {
                browser: ['es2019', 'edge88', 'firefox78', 'chrome87', 'safari13.1'],
                node: 'node16',
            },
            vueRouterMode: 'hash',
        },
        boot: ['localization', 'api'],
        css: ['app.scss'],
        extras: [
            'roboto-font',
            'material-icons',
        ],
        devServer: {
            port: 5000,
            strictPort: true,
            open: true,
            vueDevtools: true,
        },
        eslint: {
            warnings: true,
            errors: true,
        },
    };
});
```

**package.json** :

```
{
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "quasar build"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@intlify/unplugin-vue-i18n": "^1.5.0",
        "@quasar/extras": "^1.16.7",
        "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^15.2.3",
        "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^11.1.5",
        "axios": "^1.6.0",
        "flag-icons": "^6.12.0",
        "pinia": "^2.1.7",
        "quasar": "2.13.0",
        "ts-transformer-keys": "^0.4.4",
        "vue": "3.3.7",
        "vue-i18n": "^9.6.5",
        "vue-router": "^4.2.5"
    },
    "overrides": {
        "rollup": "^4.3.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@quasar/app-vite": "^1.6.2",
        "@types/node": "^20.8.10",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^6.9.1",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^6.9.1",
        "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
        "eslint": "^8.53.0",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.18.1",
        "prettier": "^3.0.3",
        "typescript": "^5.2.2"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "^18 || ^16 || ^14.19",
        "npm": ">= 6.13.4",
        "yarn": ">= 1.21.1"
    }
}
```

**tsconfig.json** :

```
{
    "extends": "@quasar/app-vite/tsconfig-preset",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "boot/*": ["src/boot/*"],
            "components/*": ["src/components/*"],
            "layouts/*": ["src/layouts/*"],
            "router/*": ["src/router/*"],
            "stores/*": ["src/stores/*"],
            "@my-temp/*": ["src/tmp/@my-temp/*"],
        }
    }
}
```